# How to override table column value with column value from second table if it exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building e-commerce application in which you can set user specific prices for products. If price for specific product for specific user is not set, it will show default product price.

It works fine, but I'm looking for more efficient solution since I'm not happy with current one.

**Tables:**

- users
- products (all product info + regular_price)
- prices (user_id, product_id, user_price)

**Models:**

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :prices
end
```

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :prices
  validates :name, presence: true

  def self.with_user_prices(current_user)
    Product.joins(
      Product.sanitize_sql_array(['LEFT OUTER JOIN prices ON prices.user_id = ?
        AND products.id = prices.product_id', current_user])
    ).select('products.*, prices.user_price')
  end
end
```

```rb
class Price < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**How I get all products with user specific prices in controller:**

```rb
@products = Product.with_user_prices(current_user)
```

**How I display them in view:**

```rb
<% @products.each do |product| %>

  <%= product.user_price ? product.user_price : product.regular_price %>

<% end %>
```

As you see I'm currently joining prices table and then in view I display user_price (prices table) if it exists, otherwise regular_price (products table).

I would love to solve everything in a single query keeping only one price column with appropriate value according to the current_user

Comment: What's your DB engine?

Comment: @MarekLipka Currently I'm using development SQLite3 database

Comment: Then my answer *should* be valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [SQL COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def self.with_user_prices(user)
    includes(:prices).where(prices: { user_id: user.id }).select(
      'products.*, COALESCE(prices.user_price, products.regular_price) as price'
    )
  end
end
```

Then you can use it simply by:

```
<%= product.price %>
```

Note that I simplified `Product.with_user_prices` method a little bit by using `includes`, which is gonna generate SQL `LEFT JOIN` query since there's condition on `prices`.

Comment: if user doesn't have any custom prices set it will return nil, otherwise:
undefined method `price' for #<Product:0x000000000d600588>

Answer (score 1):

#### New Answer:

*please do not mark this answer as correct because I just basically extended  Marek's code and yours into mine, as after several attempts I came to what you've already done anyway, but I'm just putting it here in case it helps anyone:*

**app/models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def self.with_user_prices(user)
    joins(
      sanitize_sql_array([
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN prices on prices.product_id = products.id AND prices.user_id = ?", user.id
      ])
    ).select(
      'products.*',
      'COALESCE(prices.user_price, products.regular_price) AS price_for_user'
    )
  end
end
```

**controller:**

```
@products = Product.with_user_prices(current_user)
```

**view:**

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.price_for_user %>
<% end %>
```

#### Old Answer (Inefficient Code):

Untested but can you try the following? (Not sure if this is more or less efficient than your approach)

**app/models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :prices

  def price_for_user(user)
    prices.includes(:user).where(
      users: { id: user.id }
    ).first&.user_price || regular_price
  end
end
```

**controller:**

```
# will perform LEFT OUTER JOIN (to eager load both `prices` and `prices -> user`) preventing N+1 queries
@products = Product.eager_load(prices: :user)
```

**view:**

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.price_for_user(current_user) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Technically, `Product.includes(prices: :user)` doesn't produce `left join` by default and produces three separate DB queries instead. Also, `all` at the end of it is unnecessary. Also, `Product#price_for_user` won't work, because there's no method `includes` defined on `Product` instance.

Comment: @MarekLipka hi yes. Thanks! You're absolutely right. I'm updating this now to use `eager_load` instead.

Comment: Also, you're performing separate DB query for every `Product` out there: `prices.includes(:user).where (...)`, so there's N+1 problem here.

Comment: @MarekLipka ^ this was what I was not sure yet if it will perform SQL for each product because I eager loaded it. But, as you have said, I was probably wrong. I'll try it out on a local rails app, and tweak this accordingly. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your effort. It's working correctly. Definitely a good upgrade to my solution in a direction I want to go. I believe @MarekLipka is going to perfect it :)